# No output for idf_ in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the TfidfVectorizor function in scikit-learn. I am trying to include the tf-idf element using "use_idf=True". In the docs, it says after this, result.idf_ should return the array and shape of my idf weighting, but I am getting "None". Below is my input and output. (I am eventually trying to judge how min_df and max_df effect my result, so they are just random values right now).

```
tester =TfidfVectorizer(docs_train, min_df=.2, max_df=.8, use_idf=True)

print tester

TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, charset=None,
        charset_error=None, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8',
        input=["today , war became a reality to me after seeing a screening of saving     priivate ryan . \nsteve spielberg goes beyond reality with his latest production . \nthe audience is tossed about the theatre witnessing the horror of war . \nplease keep the kids home as the r rating is for reality . \nto...esting motif out of the ubiquitous palmetto bugs-but nothing can freshen up this stale script . \n'],
    lowercase=True, max_df=0.8, max_features=None, min_df=0.2,
    ngram_range=(1, 1), norm=u'l2', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
    stop_words=None, strip_accents=None, sublinear_tf=False,
    token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', tokenizer=None, use_idf=True,
    vocabulary=None)

print tester.idf_

None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't fed the vectorizer any data. You should do so with `fit` or `fit_transform`.

Comment: Yup, I completely missed this part and it solved my problem. Thank you!